# Adding dynamic resource arguments, not blocks - Terraform

Tags: azure, terraform

I'm using a map of objects in Terraform to deploy a list of subnets in Azure.
Using a for_each I loop over all the subnets, and I already managed to use a dynamic block to include the "delegation" block for only some of the subnets.
But now I want to do something similar, which is including the argument `"service_endpoint=...."` for only one of the subnets.
But, a dynamic block can't be used I think, as this is not a block, but a single argument.
How do I approach this?

```
resource "azurerm_subnet" "subnets" {
  for_each             = var.subnets
  #name                 = "${each.key}${title(var.stage)}Subnet"
  name                 = each.key != "AzureBastion" ? "${each.key}${title(var.stage)}Subnet" : "${each.key}Subnet"
  address_prefixes     = each.value.address_prefix
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.network_rg.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.vnet.name

    dynamic "delegation" {
    for_each = each.value.databricks_subnet_delegation ? [each.key] : []
    content {
      name = "databricksDelegation"
      service_delegation {
        name = "Microsoft.Databricks/workspaces"
        actions = [
        "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets/join/action",
        "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets/prepareNetworkPolicies/action",
        "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets/unprepareNetworkPolicies/action"]
      }
    }
  }
service_endpoint : ##this should be added with only one of the subnets

}
```

Comment: Please provide complete TF code allowing for reproduction of your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a resource argument isn't set at all, that's exactly the same as explicitly setting it to `null`.

For example, if you wrote the following then the provider would see it exactly the same as if you didn't mention `service_endpoint` at all:

```
  service_endpoints = null
```

Of course explicitly assigning `null` is pointless, but you can use this knowledge to decide based on a condition whether to declare an argument:

```
  service_endpoints = condition ? ["value"] : null
```

With a declaration like the above, if `condition` is `true` then `service_endpoint` will be set to `"value"`, but if it's `false` then `service_endpoint` will be set to `null`, which is the same as not setting it at all.

You can make this even more concise by declaring the original object as having an optional attribute itself:

```
variable "subnets" {
  type = map(object({
    # ...
    service_endpoint = optional(set(string))
    # ...
  }))
}
```

Just as with resource arguments, an optional attribute in an object type is `null` when it isn't set, and so you can just assign this possibly-null value directly to the `service_endpoints` argument without any special conditional logic:

```
resource "azurerm_subnet" "subnets" {
  for_each = var.subnets

  # ...
  service_endpoints = each.value.service_endpoints
  # ...
}
```

The type constraint guarantees that `each.value.service_endpoints` will either be a set of strings or `null`, which I think matches what's allowed for `service_endpoints` on this resource type and so no extra logic is needed.